# как добавить текст картинку в высоком качестве в кнопку

Tags: android, android-studio, android-button, android-drawable

я знаю про drawableLeft в android studio, но когда используешь это, картинка ставится в реальном разрешении и не уменьшается, а если уменьшить её размер, она становится слишком размытой, вообщем мне нужно что-то подобное:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну я вижу тут два решения. Это тот что вы упомянули drawableLeft и с ним обычно все хорошо работает (может проблема в самой картинке). Второе решение это сделать отдельный лейаут с imageView и TextView

Comment: При автоматической подгонке картинки искажаются по-любому. Поэтому решение одно - изначально заготовить их в нужных размерах и качестве, и лучше всего векторные. То, что у вас на скрине - похоже из стандартного набора студии, такие можно добавить через правый клик по папке ресурсов, потом  `New->Vector Asset`. Или попробуйте добавить свои через `Image Asset` - возможно там фильтр немножко качественнее, чем на мобилке.

Comment: на скриншоте определенно векторные изображения, которые не теряют качество при масштабировании

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageButton 
android:id="@+id/imageButton" 
...
android:src="@drawable/cat"/>
```

---

Программно можно установить изображения через различные методы.

```
setImageBitmap()
setImageDrawable()    
setImageResource()    
setImageURI()
```

---

По поводу издевательства над картинкой:

```
<Button android:id=""
        android:layout_width=""
        android:layout_height=""
        android:text=""
        android:onClick="" />
```